# icCube & dynamic hierarchies that show its structure depending on TIME

Tags: olap, iccube

I would like to display a parent/child hierarchy (e.g. Costcenter) for a specific period in time.

The business case, is that the organizational structure in the Costcenter changes over time and the end-users would like to see the historical data against the latest organizational structure, but also against the structure that was valid at that time (due to link to financial statements in the past).

See screenprint for an example:[image]

Is such a thing possible in icCube?

Comment: This is what we call a 'slow changing dimension' , depens how this changes you've several solutions. Check a bit on the web, we can discuss later here

Comment: Will have a look. The solutions for slowly changing dimensions I find, are all related to how you store the data in a datawarehouse (relational database). I was referring to an implementation in icCube. I see there are several types recognized. I check which type I am referring to. Will come back later.